# is there a way to only take the data from the most recent period?

Tags: python, python-3.x, yahoo-finance, yfinance

i'm trying to take the fcf from the most recent year but i am provided with the last four. is it possible to only receive the most recent?

this is what i tried:

```
import yfinance as yf
comp = yf.Ticker("META")
print(comp.cashflow.head(n=1))
```

this is what i receive:
2022-12-31     2021-12-31     2020-12-31  2019-12-31

```
Free Cash Flow  19044000000.0  39116000000.0  23632000000.0 21212000000.0
```

is it possible to just get the 2022-12-31 figure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, `comp.cashflow` retrieves the most recent four periods of cashflow data.

To access only the most recent FCF value, you can modify the code as follows:

```py
import yfinance as yf

comp = yf.Ticker("META")
fcf = comp.cashflow.loc['Free Cash Flow']
most_recent_fcf = fcf[0]
print("Most recent FCF:", most_recent_fcf)
```

This retrieves the first column from the free cash flow array (*which I assume is always the latest data point*). If you are looking to get a specific date of FCF, then you can also modify it as such:

```py
import yfinance as yf

comp = yf.Ticker("META")
most_recent_fcf = comp.cashflow.loc['Free Cash Flow', '2022-12-31']
print("Most recent FCF:", most_recent_fcf)
```